# Does the gravitational distortion of a black hole depend of its rotation?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, orbital-motion, rotation, frame-dragging

I would like to know if there is a difference produced by the added spin of a black hole to its gravitational space-time distortion.
I am considering the distortion of space-time from a point far enough for this distortion to be “stable”.

Comment: you should read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging

Answer (score 0):

> Is the gravitational force of a black hole on a distant point same or different depending on is it spinning or not?

Different.

The gravitational field of a spinning black hole is described by the [Kerr metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric). The field of a non-spinning hole is described by the [Schwarzschild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric). They’re not the same. The former reduces to the latter when the spin goes to zero.

Both are “stable” in the sense that there are coordinate systems in which the geometry does not change with time.

As far as I know, the Kerr metric is also stable under small perturbations. (Schwarzschild can be perturbed to Kerr and vice versa, but that’s not meaningful because Schwarzschild is just a limiting case of Kerr.)

Comment: However, at sufficient distance you wouldn’t be able to tell the difference, as the higher multiple fields decay more quickly with distance than the monopole term.

Comment: What about one that's rotating very fast? Say the speed at event horizon being 0.9999c

Comment: @Astik was your comment for me or for mmeent? There’s nothing at the horizon that is moving, but a Kerr hole does have a spin parameter $a$ that can approach 1. What are you asking about such a “near-extremal” hole?

Comment: @G. Smith, my comment was meant for anyone in general.  You had mentioned in your answer that kerr metric can be taken as a perturbation of non rotating metric, so I am assuming that the rotation is "small" enough to be considered a perturbation. What I meant by having a speed of 0.999...c at the horizon is to have a very high rotational velocity

Comment: In that case, is the perturbation assumption still valid?

Comment: @Astik My guess is that a perturbation can cause a hole with $a<1$ to become one with $a>1$, but I’m not sure about this. I think meent may be more of an expert on this.

Comment: @Astik Hmmm... on second thought, I guess that would be problematic in terms of naked singularities, so maybe it can’t happen.

Comment: @mmeent can you please comment on this? Or link some source that i can follow? If I remember correctly, the stress energy tensor can't be calculated for a blackhole(theoretically) because we don't know the internal dynamics of the hole. Hence, normally, its modelled as a plasma or a fluid.

Comment: No, the stress tensor is known. For a Kerr hole it’s zero except at the singularity. Both the external and internal metric is known. Kerr holes are not modeled as a plasma or fluid. You might be thinking of the Friedmann metric.